# Optimizing DB queries

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I need to verify existence of entities in the database.

```
 If db_is_team_exist(team_id):
     If db_is_user_exist_by_id(user_id):
         ok
     else:
         raise ObjectDoesNotExist("user", user_id)
 else:
     raise ObjectDoesNotExist("team", team_id)
```

Query functions in the database:

```
def db_is_team_exist(team_id: str) -> bool:
    cursor.execute(f "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM teams WHERE id='{team_id}';")
    return bool(cursor.fetchone()[0])

def db_is_user_exist_by_id(user_id: str) -> bool:
    cursor.execute(f "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users WHERE id='{user_id}';")
    return bool(cursor.fetchone()[0])
```

Sometimes there are too many of these checks for me to afford such a load on the database. Is there any way to check existence of two+ entities which are in different tables with one query? Or reduce the number of queries in the database in another way?

Comment: Why do you need to make these checks?

Comment: @snakecharmerb. This is part of the API code, when a client requests an entity I need to check if the user who sent the request exists and if the entity he is requesting exists.

Comment: It's impossible to be sure without seeing some example code (and tables), but if the database is well-constructed, it might be easier to go ahead and attempt whatever it is the API does and handle the errors if an entity is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can technically use a single query like:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM teams WHERE id='{team_id}')
    AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM users WHERE id='{user_id}')
```

Please use proper parameterized queries though.

Comment: Does it save any time? In fact, inside the SELECT 1 query I make the same two queries

Comment: Yes as it is one round trip to the database and one statement prepare and execution. It also stops execution of the "sub-queries" when the first hit is found rather than counting hits.

Comment: Thank you very much. It`s really faster